# Docstrings for Dagster wrapped functions not appearing in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, dagster

I've got a project written in python with use of pypspark and now dagster.  We are using Sphinx to build the documentation and napoleon to parse the Google style docstrings.  We've started including prewrapped dagster solids like the following:

```
@solid(
    config_schema={
        "join_key": String,
        "join_style": String,
        "df1_name": String,
        "df2_name": String,
    }
)
def join_two_dfs_solid(
    context, df1: SparkDataFrame, df2: SparkDataFrame
) -> SparkDataFrame:
    """
    Solid to join two DataFrames on the sepcified key.

    Args:
        context (dict): Dagster Context Dict
        df1 (SparkDataFrame): Spark DataFrame with the same schema
        df2 (SparkDataFrame): Spark DataFrame with the same schema

    Config Parameters:
        join_key (str): name of column to join on.  Specified column must exist in both columns.
        join_style (str): spark join style, e.g., "left", "inner", "outer", etc.; default is "inner"
        df1_name (str): alias name for the first dataframe.
        df2_name (str): alias name for the second dataframe.

    Returns:
        DataFrame
    """
    key = context.solid_config["join_key"]
    join_style = context.solid_config.get("join_style", "inner")
    df1_name = context.solid_config["df1_name"]
    df2_name = context.solid_config["df2_name"]

    context.log.info(f"Running join of two dataframes on {key}")
    check_required_columns(df1, [key])
    check_required_columns(df2, [key])

    output = df1.alias(df1_name).join(
        df2.alias(df2_name),
        sf.col(f"{df1_name}.{key}") == sf.col(f"{df2_name}.{key}"),
        how=join_style,
    )
    return output
```

When we go to build with sphinx-apidoc, I can see that docstring for the function exists by checking `join_two_dfs_solid.__doc__` and the dagster attached `join_two_dfs_solid._description` field is empty, which should mean that it uses the docstring.  However, when the sphinx docs build, I get a blank .rst file for the module containing this solid.  Does anyone know if there are any other configuration settings in sphinx or the solid that I need to change to get this to build correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an open issue that the team is aware of https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/2427

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for a solution to this (a year later, I know), I've just added a Sphinx plugin to the [dagstd](https://github.com/isaacharrisholt/dagstd) library to take care of this.

You just need to install the library and add this to your `conf.py` file:

```
    extensions = [
        ...
        'dagstd.sphinx.parser',
    ]
```

By default, this will prefix all op documentation with `(op)`. To change
this, add the following to your `conf.py` file:

```
    dagstd_op_prefix = 'My Prefix'
```

Comment: Good to know - our project eventually moved away from dagster because we kept finding the need for a helper library like this and key functionality became more coupled with the dagster UI. I hope things like this are incorporated into the dragster native ecosystem!